# Shared drive folders disappear when user has no rights?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, shared-folders, shared-access

So, I am working on a scenario where I want users to be able to see all folders up to a certain point. When they get to a file or folder they are not allowed into, I want them to be able to see it, click it, and get an error saying they do not have permissions. Currently, when I give them rights, they can see it and move through the folder, but when I take the rights away, the folder disappears, as if it never existed! Does anyone know why this is happening? Its not a "Hidden file" since I have enabled that in the options. The item is invisible until they get rights to it, which it is then visible for them to access. The server where the folders are located is Windows server 2012 R2, and I am at a complete loss.

Comment: "Currently, when I give them rights" - Can you be more specific, what rights are you granting them, if a Windows user can see a file, it means they can read and open the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are talking about is “Access Based Enumeration.” It cause Windows Server to not show files and folders a user does not have at least read permissions on.

It is a property of the file share and is changed by going in to server manager and navigating to “shares” then right-clicking and changing the properties of the share in question.

Answer (score 0):

There are two sets of [permissions](https://blog.varonis.com/ntfs-permissions-vs-share/) you need to set:  File/folder permissions and share permissions.  If you give them file/folder access they can see the files/folders, but if they don't have the proper share permissions, they cant access them.